# Como utilizar método parse() em javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-service

**Tenho a seguinte implementação:**

```js
minhaDataRetornada = "Dez 20, 2016";
minhaDataTratada = Date.parse(minhaDataRetornada);
console.log(minhaDataTratada);
```

Executando o código acima, meu retorno é :NaN.

Se eu alterar a palavra `Dez` para `Dec`, funciona perfeitamente.

Gostaria de saber como resolver, pois meu `webService` retorna `Dez`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) espera uma string de representação de datas no formato [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) ou ISO 8601 (outros formatos podem ser utilizados, mas os resultados podem não ser os esperados).

No caso dos nomes do mês, o esperado é em inglês:

> month-name = "Jan" / "Feb" / "Mar" / "Apr" / "May" / "Jun" / "Jul" / "Aug"               "Sep" / "Oct" / "Nov" / "Dec"

O que pode ser uma solução é renomear os meses antes de fazer parse, algo como:

```js
var mesesEn = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug", "Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],
    mesesPt = ["Jan","Fev","Mar","Abr","Mai","Jun","Jul","Ago", "Set","Out","Nov","Dez"];

minhaDataRetornada = "Dez 20, 2016";

// verifica se o mês para renomeá-lo
if (mesesPt.indexOf(minhaDataRetornada.split(" ")[0]) !== -1)
  var idx = mesesPt.indexOf(minhaDataRetornada.split(" ")[0]);
  minhaDataRetornada = minhaDataRetornada.replace(mesesPt[idx], mesesEn[idx]);

minhaDataTratada = Date.parse(minhaDataRetornada);
console.log(minhaDataTratada);
```